# How do I make cfimage work with ColdFusion 10 on Apache?

Tags: apache, tomcat, coldfusion, osx-lion, coldfusion-10

I just upgraded from ColdFusion9 to ColdFusion10 on OS X running the included Apache web server.  Now all of my images that I was writing to the browser using cfimage with the writeToBrowser option throw 404 errors.

Under CF9, I had previously set my web server up to use a few virtual directories with a self-signed cert to enable SSL.  I don't think SSL is part of the problem, but the more you know, the better.

It looks like there is just a missing mapping of some sort that doesn't get made during the installation process (which I've done a few times with the same results).

I tried adding an alias to the CFFileServlet directory which changed my 404s to 403s, but I am unsure what to do to correct that since all of the filesystem properties show read for everybody.

Is there some guidance out there on how to set up the virtual directories to make the CFFileServlet location work in my websites?

If I look in the actual directory, the files are getting created there correctly.

Here is a sample of what's in my virtualHosts file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxxxxxxxxx"
        ServerName xxxxxxxxxx.local
        DirectoryIndex index.cfm
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Alias /CFIDE /Library/WebServer/Documents/CFIDE
        Alias /mxunit /Library/WebServer/Documents/mxunit

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

        RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxxxxxxxx.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/xxxxxxxxxx.key

        DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents/xxxxxxxxxx"
        ServerName xxxxxxxxxx.local
        DirectoryIndex index.cfm
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Alias /CFIDE /Library/WebServer/Documents/CFIDE
        Alias /mxunit /Library/WebServer/Documents/mxunit
    </VirtualHost>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much trial and error and looking at the post on Ben Nadel's site, I finally got this working.  I decided to put this in the mod_jk.conf file that the CF10 install creates so I could keep all the cf specific stuff together.  At the bottom of the file I added an alias and set the permissions on the location as so:

```
Alias /CFFileServlet "/Applications/ColdFusion10/cfusion/tmpCache/CFFileServlet"
<Directory "/Applications/ColdFusion10/cfusion/tmpCache/CFFileServlet">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

After doing that, all my images lit right up.

I'm going to mark this entry as the answer since it has the details about how to get this working, but I'll award the bounty to Kevin for pointing me in the right direction.  Thanks Kevin!

Comment: Glad you got it working (and thanks for posting the solution for the next guy).

Answer (score 1):

If using VirtualHosts in Apache you need to use the JkMountCopy directive. See the [Apache Tomcat Connector documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html), particularly the JkMountCopy directive.

Comment: Thanks! I added `JKMountCopy All` in my mod_jk.conf File to get Tomcat handle requests to CFFileServlet folder.

Answer (score 1):

CF10 on Ubuntu 12.10 with Apache cfimage was showing blank page, added the following to "/etc/apache2/mod_jk.conf".

```
Alias /CFFileServlet "/opt/coldfusion10/cfusion/tmpCache/CFFileServlet"
<Directory "/opt/coldfusion10/cfusion/tmpCache/CFFileServlet/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then restarted Apache, cfimage writeToBrowser working now.

Comment: I need to add this to the <Directory> directive in order to get permission to access the folder: Require all granted

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have already tried it, but this [url](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1868-URL-Rewriting-And-ColdFusion-s-WriteToBrowser-Image-Functionality-CFFileServlet-.htm) explains the solution to the issue you have described. It talks mainly about IIS but if you look at the comments below, the same solution has been tried on Apache too.

Comment: Can you summarize the salient points of the solution ? (Links often break)

Answer (score 0):

For CF10 Standard on Linux with Apache and the standard installation dir, you can also use this one:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/CFFileServlet/(.*) /opt/coldfusion10/cfusion/tmpCache/CFFileServlet/$1 [L]
```

Add it to `/etc/httpd/conf/mod_jk.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in IIS 8 on Windows Server 2008 by adding a "CFFileServlet " virtual directory to "C:\Coldfusion10\cfusion\tmpCache\CFFileServlet". At first it didn't work, then I discovered I had a rewrite rule enabled that was converting all URL's to lowercase. Apparently this was case sensitive. After disabling that rewrite rule, my CFCaptcha images work again!

Answer (score 0):

One poster Joel had an issue with the case sensitive nature of this mapping...

Edit C:\ColdFusion10\cfusion\wwwroot\WEB-INF\web.xml and change the url-pattern of the servlet mapping to lowercase then restart the CF application server will fix the issue

Note that the CFFileServlet version will not longer work anymore. If you have  server running multiple CF sites and not all of them have a URL rewrite to set to lower case, then some will break.

Comment: Good to know. Though the [referenced answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20912803/104223) does mention it is case sensitive, so this should probably be a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)  (I realize you cannot post comments yet, just FYI).